# What's the difference between "I'm happy" and "I have a happy heart"?

Tags: meaning

What's the difference? Could you say that romantically? About an infant?

Comment: Say what? The former or the latter?

Comment: Thanks for those answers. I wanted to understand how it could relate to emotions expressed by an adult or if you could say that about a happy child as you look at him/her.

Answer (score 3):

**I'm happy**  is a simple sentence that expresses the state of mind of the person (Subject) at that particular instance. There will be a specific reason behind the happiness expressed on the sentence.

For example:  I am happy to know that you got state first in board exams.

**I have a happy heart**  is poetic self explanation of his character by the Subject (I). This expresses that the person is easy going and he doesn't have any stress or hard feelings dumped on his mind. A state of peace.

For example:  I have a happy heart despite the serious problems in my life.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm happy** can be said about anything.

**I have a happy heart** is quirky/comical/poetic and isn't heard very much, at least not where I am (UK).

Comment: I've not heard it much in the US, either. I wonder where the OP heard it.

Answer (score 0):

If the OP is seeking a more emphatic or emotional expression than "I am happy", "My heart is filled with joy" is a much more common expression than referring to a "happy heart."

Romantic happiness and happiness about the birth of a child would definitely call for something more expressive than "I am happy," unless I am reading too much into this question.

Answer (score 0):

Being happy; Being yourself w/o the emotions, w/o worrying about health issues. You're stuck in that moment of being you and living a life you deserve. 
Happy Heart; you get these butterflies of your heart being "very happy." Romantic, eyes glaring, beautiful compliments... Not only do you smile, but your heart does too.